# java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed

Tags: android

I got this code error when I build project. my gradle build sync successfully done.

I have searched this error but nothing works. I also looked on stackoverflow.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to
```

this is my gradle code:-

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "stechrey.rwdbiharemail"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.4"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

classpaths:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

I expect the output successfully, but the actual output is error. I am new to programming. please help me.

Comment: Why don't you migrate to AndroidX?

Comment: This question has been asked many times and there are many SO answers about this problem. You can refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257779/9968399)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is thrown cause one of your libraries is been coded in androidX and you are using 28 support library . Mismatch is occured due to it .Try using a older version of such library or migrate your project to androidx